# Update a table's own column with multiple INNER JOIN and UPDATE

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

Trying to use Multiple INNER JOIN while using UPDATE.  Here's what I want to achieve:
Update Table1's Students and Teachers column by multiply the relative expense rate,
where Table1 & 3 match their class_Num to decides which expense rate type to use in Table 2
and match table1 & 2 match their month to get the expense rate

Here's my unable to finish's query:

```
  SELECT Table3.expense_type as ANS
  FROM
    ((
    Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 
    ON Table3.Class_Num = Table1.Class_Num)
    INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table2.Month = Table1.Month);
```

EDIT: with above Query I can get the expense type i wanted to use in table2, but how can it fits into an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use a text value as a column name, so when your query gets the expense_type, you cannot just make that into a column reference. So you need to make a mapping from text value to column, which you can do with the [`Switch`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) function.

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE    (Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
        ON Table2.Month = Table1.Month)
INNER JOIN Table3 
        ON Table3.Class_Num = Table1.Class_Num
SET        Table1.Students = Table1.Students *
               Switch(Table3.expense_type='expense1', Table2.expense1,
                      Table3.expense_type='expense2', Table2.expense2,
                      Table3.expense_type='expense3', Table2.expense3),
           Table1.Teacher  = Table1.Teacher *                   
               Switch(Table3.expense_type='expense1', Table2.expense1,
                      Table3.expense_type='expense2', Table2.expense2,
                      Table3.expense_type='expense3', Table2.expense3);
```

Comment: thanks!  Didn't know Case can be used.   However, it gives error at the first CASE:  Syntax error (missing operators) in query expression 'Table1.Students = Table1.Students * CASE...

Comment: Just did, however same syntax error, i'm testing to see what's wrong too

Comment: Ah, I just read it is not supported in MS Access. Needs to be done with `Switch(...)`. Answer updated!

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank you very much!  Now i know Switch can be use in such way.